# Как узнать на какие сервера бот discord включен( python )

Tags: python, discord.py

Всем привет! У меня такая проблема. Я хочу сделать разумного бота который с нуля будет редактировать и переделать сервер на более красивую. Но для этого пришла самая первая проблема - на какие сервера он подключен. Если его подключили то он должен знать какое имя сервера чтобы именно туда добавить каналы. Основый код слишком маленький так как я недавно только добавил...

```py
import discord as ds
@bot.event
async def on_message():
    pass # сюда
```

Я не знаю команду(я поискал в документе дискода) и поэтому решил спросить у вас.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это есть в документаци

```
bot.guilds
```

Comment: Я только что посмотрел и оказывается это ответ на вопрос